# Elastic search scroll aggregations

Tags: url, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to get a unique document count in an index based on an id property via elastic search web API. The thing is that I have millions of entries. How can I scroll on an aggregation ? 
this is the url:

http://my.servers.ip:9200/index_name/doc_type/_search?scroll=1m

And this is the body:

```
{
  "_source": "false",
    "aggs" : {
        "Ids" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "somePropertyIWantToGoupBy",
                "size" : 100
            },
             "aggs": {
                "unique": {
                    "cardinality": {
                        "field": "someCategoryIWantUniqueCount"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },"size":0
}
```

I get the scrollId , but on the next call with scroll id I'll get the next 100 aggregations, instead I get an empty result set.

Is it possible to scroll on aggregations ?
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to paginate terms aggregation.

You should use [Composite Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) but it's a beta aggregation and might be removed or changed in the future...